# Searching for substrings (NSString)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, substr

What's the best way to search for substring that are enclosed by ## $$. So for example, I have some text like this:

Lorem **##ipsum$$** dolor sit amet, **##consectetur$$** adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

I want to get the words **ipsum** and **consectetur**. I know I can do NSString rangeofsubstring method, but is there a better way to do this? Basically, find a string enclosed by 2 other strings?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your can use [`NSRegularExpression`](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (warning: iOS4+ only) to match your substrings using a RegEx pattern (like `@"##.*$$"` typically).

It is then really easy to iterate thru the resulting matches (my preferred way is using an enumeration block, as we are un iOS4 :-)):

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"##(.*)$$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:yourString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [yourString length]) usingBlock:
    ^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
        NSRange range = [match rangeAtIndex:1]; // range of string in first parens
        NSString* oneWord = [yourString substringWithRange:range];
    }
];
```

---

*Note: If you need to support pre-iOS4 versions, you can check [`NSPredicate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html) but it is much less flexible (... and I guess that for pre-iOS4, using rangeOfSubstring is probably the best choice anyway as NSPredicate will only tell you if a string is matching but won't allow you to get the substring...)*

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through string characters, searching for '##', and after that search for nearest '$$'.